# Why can't I change my macbook's backlight?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, backlight

So apparently I cannot modify my Macbook's backlight using the keyboard shortcut:

[image]

I'm pretty sure it will work again if I restart it. But I wonder what may cause this: is it perhaps an issue with my hardware, or just some OS glitch caused by something insignificant?

Macbook Pro Retina, 15" mid 2014. El Capitan 10.11.

Answer (score 1):

You set it with the F5 and F6 keys, and it should not change after that, except for the setting SystemPreferences->Keyboard->Keyboard  "adjust keyboard brightness in low light".

Comment: Did you even read the original post? The screenshot in the question shows what happens when you try using the F5/F6 keys to adjust the brightness when this bug occurs.